# Django : go back to correct paginator page

Tags: python, django, paginator

I have simple blog app that is using paginator for listing articles.

I want to be able to add button in article detail page that will direct user to same page that this article is on.

I want to take slug from current url and send it to paginator so that it directs user to ?page=X where article is on.

I checked paginator docs and didn't find any info on how to retrieve page number of specific object.

my views:

```
def blog(request):
    posts = Article.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 3) 
    page = request.GET.get('page') 
    posts = paginator.get_page(page) 
    return render(request,'blog.html',{'posts':posts})

def article_id(request,slug):
    articleid = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blogid.html', {'article':articleid})
```

my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.blog, name = 'blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.article_id, name = 'article_id'),
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the position of the object via

```
position=Article.objects.filter(your_filter_key=your_filter_value).order_by('other_filter_order').count()
```

Then get the page number via

```
items_per_page=yout_items_per_page
page = int(position/items_per_page)
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Can you explain what should I be filtering by ?

Comment: He is suggesting you can just calculate which page the article is on and return the page (possibly as a redirect).

Comment: @KevinHe I know where is he coming from. I am just trying to figure out position part but I am on good track.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with help of Giancarlo's answer.

I added below to article_id

```
def article_id(request,slug):
articleid = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
position = Article.objects.filter(date__gt=articleid.date).count()
page = str(int((position)/3)+1)
return render(request, 'blogid.html', {'article':articleid, 'page':page})
```

And then in template link looks like /blog/?page={{page}}